# Sort By Boolean value in Spring Data

Tags: sorting, boolean, spring-data

I'm using Spring Data and I have a repo method returning some Products. I need to sort the result List By Availability, the available products should be displayed first.

Product has a boolean field 'available'. In order to achieve the sorting by availability I'm trying to define my repository method with something like

```
List<Product> findAllOrderByAvailable();
```

but it doesn't work. 
Any idea if this is achievable with Spring Data?

Answer (score 3):

Following the [Spring Data Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation) , you have to insert a `By` after `findAll` to indicate thats where the criteria starts, and you're also missing the order `Asc` or `Desc`, so it should look like this:

`List<Product> findAllByOrderByAvailableAsc(); //or Desc`